# How to perform Streaming of twitter data via Apache Spark Streaming?

Tags: spark-streaming

How to perform Streaming of twitter data via Apache Spark Streaming?

Previously I had fetched the twitter data via flume and stored in HDFS ,where I configured the twitter login credentials in conf.txt.

But now got stuck in fetching twitter data via Apache Spark Streaming.

Problem is with placing twitter login credentials..
Please help me..

Comment: what have you done so far and what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: if(args.length<5)
 {
 String consumerKey=args[0];
 String consumerSecret=args[1];
 String accessToken=args[2];
 String accessTokenSecret=args[3];

Comment: System.out.println("Spark Streaming Demonstration with Twitter");
  
   System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey",consumerKey);
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret",consumerSecret);
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken",accessToken);
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret",accessTokenSecret);
    String[] filters={"#Android"};  System.out.println("JavaStreamingContext created");

Comment: SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Twitterpopulartags");JavaStreamingContext ssc=new JavaStreamingContext(conf,new Duration(10000)); System.out.println("twitterStatus created"); JavaDStream<String> statuses = twitterStatus.map(
      new Function<Status, String>() {public String call(Status status) { return status.getText(); }
       }
      );statuses.print();ssc.start();ssc.awaitTermination();}}}

Comment: error:Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: There was problem with the jdk version ..now it got cleared..

Comment: The error now is:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Please add the code the the question. For that last exception, what do you think the program will do if I pass only 1, 2 or 3 parameters?

Comment: yeah I got cleared ..

Comment: But their are other errors that exit..trying to solve..

Comment: Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/NetworkInputDStream

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use sc.setLocalProperties()?
create a

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[10]", "test", Duration(3000))
val sc = ssc.sparkContext
```

and

```
sc.setLocalProperties()
```